# OC4J 10.1.3 and Expression Language (EL) conflict

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oc4j

I'm working on a project that is currently migrating from Apache Tomcat 6 to OC4J (due to the client's specifications).

The problem is that we're getting this:

2012-02-08 18:23:53.091 NOTIFICATION  J2EE JSP-0008 Error: Exception Oracle.classloader.util.AnnotatedNoClassDefFoundError:

```
  Class not found: javax.el.ELException

Classe dependente: oracle.jsp.parse.JspBeanInfo
         Carregador: oc4j:10.1.3
    Origem do Código: /C:/Users/cvgpb/Desktop/Oracle-OC4J/j2ee/home/lib/ojsp.jar
  Configuração: <code-source> in META-INF/boot.xml in C:\Users\cvgpb\Desktop\Oracle-OC4J\j2ee\home\oc4j.jar
```

We're using, as you can see, OC4J 10.1.3.
Almost every page on the project is using ELs...
The only alternative is to use scriptlets but that would take long time.

We must use EL and OC4J 10.1.3 otherwise it'll cost too much to rebuild all the pages.
**How can I manage to solve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`javax.el.ELException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ELException.html) is introduced in JSP/EL 2.1 which goes hand in hand with Servlet 2.5 which is part of Java EE 5. Tomcat 6.0 is a Servlet 2.5 compatible container.

OC4J 10.1.3, however, is an ancient J2EE 1.4 container, supporting only Servlet 2.4.

As long as your webapp's `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 2.4, all the code is programmed against the Servlet 2.4 / JSP 2.0 APIs, the `/WEB-INF/lib` does *not* contain servletcontainer specific libraries such as a copy of `jsp-api.jar` from Tomcat 6, and the webapp runs perfectly fine on Tomcat 5.5 (which is also a Servlet 2.4 container), then it should in theory work as good on OC4J 10.1.3.

This particular error indicates that you have libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib` which are either copied from Tomcat 6, or have in turn Servlet 2.5 dependencies, such as for example JSF 2.0. Cleanup the `/WEB-INF/lib` and/or downgrade the involved libraries to Servlet 2.4 compatible versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We're now managing to downgrade the libraries =/

Comment: You're welcome. Another option is to upgrade or replace OC4J by a Servlet 2.5 compatible one. Servlet 2.4 is really end of life for long. I'd discuss with the serveradmins that they're basically working with oudated/dead software.